# Counting String Matches in a Range

Tags: google-sheets

Currently I'm using this formula to count the number of string matches in a range:

> =COUNTA(FILTER(D3:D723,FIND(A1, D3:D723)))

If `A1="am"` and range has `"ham"`, `"scammy"`, `"pan"`; then the cell will display `2`.

It appears to work correctly, except for one thing- it displays a match of 1 if there are no matches. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D723,"*"&A1&"*")
```

It counts the amount of cells in D3:D7243 that have the substring in Cell A1. The * are there as a wildcard in front and behind the substring.

I made a [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApNTZI1iT9tCdGdHNHlfdG5CMkd2c0o2d0ZOX2Z2dGc&usp=sharing) for you as well to look at.

UPDATE: fixed statement

Comment: It works for my situation, though this is purely case insensitive. I would have liked to have seen a solution that could also be case sensitive if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula you are looking for.

### Formula

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(B:B,FIND(IF(A1="",(1/0),A1), B:B))),"")
```

### Results

Search for `A`:
[image]

Search for empty string:
[image]

Search for `am`:
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file you you: **[Counting String Matches in a Range](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFhvYzBfLW05QUZRYlZyZUYxSW1Oa3c&usp=sharing)**