# Count cells with same string in dynamic range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, countif

I've read many articles on Google and StackOverflow, but haven't found any that mention how to count cells (under the same column) containing same string value. The count only considers a part of the sheet: many cells are added/removed in a short time, so the range keeps changing length. In the same sheet there are several ranges, separated by a blank row.

The counters should refer to a single range (counter_1 --> range_1; counter_2 --> range_2 , etc.).

e.g.: if cells can show 4 different options AND there are 5 dynamic ranges in the sheet --> there will be 4 counters for each range (4*5).

Following several websites (like [this](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/count-cells-with-specific-text-in-google-sheets/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786359/counting-string-matches-in-a-range) and [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)), I attempted to implement this check function directly from the sheet, without involving AppsScript.

E.g.: if I add this function in D2, E2, F2, G2 (watch the table below for reference):

```
COUNTIF(B2:B2,”1st option”) in D2 ; COUNTIF(B2:B2,”2nd option”) in E2 ; COUNTIF(B2:B2,”3rd option”) in F2 ; COUNTIF(B2:B2,”4th option”) in G2
```

Each counter will check its condition and update its cell value. This will be done only for cells grouped under "1st department".

The problem is that I have to add 16 counters manually (4 options for 4 departments) and, if an item is added/removed, all counters will throw an error. I can't divide departments in different sheets as a workaround.

My sheet is as follows:

| Department | Option |  | 1st option counter | 2nd option counter | 3rd option counter | 4th option counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | "2nd option" |  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2nd | "1st option" |  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2nd | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3rd | "4th option" |  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3rd | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4th | "3rd option" |  | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4th | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4th | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |

After some items were added/removed:

| Department | Option |  | 1st option counter | 2nd option counter | 3rd option counter | 4th option counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st | "2nd option" |  | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1st | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2nd | "1st option" |  | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2nd | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2nd | "1st option" |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3rd | "4th option" |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3rd | "2nd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3rd | "3rd option" |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4th | "3rd option" |  | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 4th | "3rd option" |  |  |  |  |  |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `all counters will throw an error.` What's the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; probably I didn't explain clearly the concept. Actually, no error is displayed in the sheet: the error lies in not counting cells added after defining the range. In case of deleted values, however, the COUNTIF function updates perfectly, without throwing any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-array answer. The only reason this might be helpful compared to the above two answers is if you have **a lot** of calculations going and you begin to hit some performance issues. The obvious drawback to the below formula is that you would have to reapply it by dragging down after changes were made. You could build in an app script to reapply the formula as an `r1C1` during an `onEdit` event.

Put this in all cells in columns `D:G` and assuming `D1:G1` have the matching count syntax (i.e D1=1st Option)

```
=if(And($A2<>"",OR(Row($A2)=2,$A1="")),SUMPRODUCT((--($A:$A=$A2))*(--(D$1=$B:$B))),)
```

Again the first two answers offer a dynamic solution, which is probably better, but I figured I'd add this just for illustration or maybe to ignite some other ideas.

Comment: Nice too! I was about to offer a non array option, but had to leave! Another option if OP doesn't need to have exactly like that is to have a Query that gathers all the information. I'll leave it here in case it is useful: `=QUERY(A2:B;"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B")` - or even `=MAP(QUERY(A2:B;"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B"),LAMBDA(f,IF(f="",0,f)))` if 0s are needed

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your suggestions!
The non-array answer is perfect for those who hit performance issues and need lighter but stable formulas.
The significant drawback of the function by pgSystemTester is that it's non-dynamic. That doesn't mean it won't help others with different purposes!
For my goal, I preferred the adoption of the QUERY by @Martín , which went even further (hiding 0-count options).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this formula in D2:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A);4;LAMBDA(r;c;IF(AND(INDEX(A2:A;r)<>"";INDEX(A1:A;r)<>INDEX(A2:A;r));COUNTIFS(A2:A;INDEX(A2:A;r);B2:B;INDEX(D1:1;c));"")))
```

[image]

You can see it working [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RMu7eYwL8lgYGSOnixfhzDJIPF4jdsisY4A_hYyxWSs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Sharp formula. I need to brush up on the `MakeArray` function. 

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried your formula and it works perfectly.
However, as you and @pgSystemTester later mentioned, with lots of calculations going on the MAKEEARRAY function often hits performance issues, making it unreliable (for my goal).
Definitely a valid solution though!

Answer (score 0):

```
function countcellswithsamestring() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastRow());
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let co = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      if(!co.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        co[c] = {count:1,loc:[sh.getRange(row + i,col + j).getA1Notation()]}
        co.pA.push(c);
      } else {
        co[c].count++;
        co[c].loc.push(sh.getRange(row + i,col + j).getA1Notation()) 
      }
    })
  })
  let o = co.pA.map(c => [c,co[c].count,co[c].loc.join(',')]);
  osh.clearContents();
  o.unshift(["String","Count","Locations"])
  osh.getRange(1,1, o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 10 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 9 | 8 | 3 | 8 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 2 | 10 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 9 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 7 |

Output:

| String | Count | Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 11 | A2,H4,D5,H6,I7,G8,H8,I8,E10,J11,C12 |
| 10 | 5 | B2,C8,D8,C9,F9 |
| 0 | 15 | C2,F3,E4,I4,C5,A7,B7,C7,B9,D9,H9,A10,B10,C10,D10 |
| 5 | 13 | D2,H2,A3,D3,A4,C4,D4,J5,C6,C11,E11,B12,H12 |
| 1 | 10 | E2,C3,B4,D6,J7,J9,G10,G11,I11,E12 |
| 2 | 6 | F2,I2,H7,B8,E9,G12 |
| 4 | 12 | G2,F4,B5,A6,G6,E7,A8,E8,F8,H10,H11,F12 |
| 3 | 7 | J2,I3,J4,E5,I5,I6,D11 |
|  | 22 | K2,L2,K3,L3,K4,L4,K5,L5,K6,L6,K7,L7,K8,L8,K9,L9,K10,L10,K11,L11,K12,L12 |
| 7 | 10 | B3,A5,B6,E6,D7,F7,A9,I10,D12,J12 |
| 8 | 12 | E3,H3,J3,G4,F5,H5,G9,I9,J10,A11,F11,I12 |
| 9 | 9 | G3,G5,F6,J6,G7,J8,F10,B11,A12 |

Comment: Thank you! However, your suggestion has the entire sheet as its range, not accounting for the existence of other dynamic ranges.
Moreover, using a script versus a sheet function could affect performance more (especially if multiple scripts are running).