# Query to count cells changes cell's range randomly, by itself

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I refer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907781/count-cells-with-same-string-in-dynamic-range).
The problem happens when I use the non-array solution proposed by @Martín (the one that overloaded less my system).

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:B;"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

By itself the Query() works perfectly, but only with non-dynamic ranges. The function, put in "Sheet2", draws the data to be counted from "Sheet1". The range in which the function is applied is a portion of "Sheet1", that's why I entered "Sheet1!A2:B".

In "Sheet1", new cells are constantly added and the sheet automatically organizes the answers into different categories (first_department, second_department, ...). To do this, it adds blank rows between groups of cells (different categories), removes rows in the wrong category to move them in the correct one, removes all blank rows at the end (useless part of the sheet).

At this point, the Query() in "Sheet2" has some error which leads it to consider a range outside the one originally set (it's always the number of cells on the sheet + 1), raising a "#VALUE!".

Function before:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:B;"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

Function after (an example):

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A23:B;"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

In this case there were 22 cells in "Sheet1", and the Query() went to "A:23".

I've tried myself to solve the issue in the past week, trying to simulate the situation that led to the problem. I've updated the organization of "Sheet1" by adding new data or deleting some: I haven't been able to find out the source of the error. When I checked the query's behaviour, the range rightly locked at "A2:B", it didn't end up at "A23:B".

I tried deleting the entire sheet and creating a new one from scratch (maybe it was a local bug), I tried changing Google Sheet's country of use (maybe it was punctuation), but that didn't fix anything. I've looked at the Query() and it's, indeed for me, correct under all shapes.

Is there a way to lock the range, so that it doesn't change randomly?

I'd appreciate any effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a common issue, you can use INDIRECT to lock the range:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:B");"Select A,COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

Comment: Thanks @Martín! That solved instantly my issue.